# how to calculate the frequency of the random numbers in python

Tags: python, random

i would like to generate random numbers for 5 minutes. after that, i would like to know the most common numbers.

my question is:

1:how to manually interrupt the code after some amount of time(i am not sure about the time, the time is flexible, sometimes it can be 5minutes 30 seconds, sometimes it can be 4minutes 59 seconds),therefore i prefer to manually interrupt the code.

2:how to count the most common numbers

each set of numbers is 4 digits. therefore, i would like to generate the numbers of 0000 instead of 0

for example i generate the following numbers:
1:2578
2:3456
3:2578
4:9999
5:2578

i want to find the most common numbers which are 2578.

following is my code.

```
import random
while True:
    number=[random.randint(0,9)for value in range(0,4)]
    print(f"{number[0]}{number[1]}{number[2]}{number[3]}")
```

after reading the solutions given by members, my solution is as follows:

```
import random
from collections import Counter
t_end = time.time() + 60*2
numbers = []
while time.time() < t_end:
    number=''.join(map(str, [random.randint(0,9)for value in range(0,4)]))
    numbers.append(number)

print(Counter(numbers))
```

let's say i set the time at 2 minutes, can i terminate the script at 1 minute and get the result?

Comment: Did you try [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: the problem is that after i ran the code for 5 minutes,i got tons of new random numbers, i needed to terminate the code, and inserted the new code to find the most common numbers.

Comment: Then there are two separate questions: how to interrupt the code after five minutes, and how to count the most common numbers.

Comment: you are right. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Set time as you want

```
from collections import Counter
import time
#10 sec
t_end = time.time() + 10
arr = []

while time.time() < t_end:
    #print(time.time())
    arr.append(random.randint(0,100))

arr = Counter(arr)
print(arr.most_common(3))
```

Output:

```
[(54, 74), (52, 71), (83, 66)]
```

Comment: thank you for being helpful. appreciate it. anyway i have edited the question. can you read it again?thanks again.

Comment: hi, time time is an useful function. however, let's say i set the time at 10 minutes, can i terminate it at 9 minutes 45 seconds and get the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can try that

```py
import random
from collections import Counter

i=0
numbers = []
while i<100000:
    numbers.append(random.randint(0,9999))
    i += 1

print(Counter(numbers))
```

Or if you want to keep your 4 digits format :

```py
import random
from collections import Counter

i=0
numbers = []
while i<1000:
    number=''.join(map(str, [random.randint(0,9)for value in range(0,4)]))
    numbers.append(number)
    i += 1

print(Counter(numbers))
```

Comment: hi your code is good. however, i want to find every number in 4 digits. for example, 0001 instead of 1, 0000 instead of 0

Comment: thank you for being helpful. appreciate it. anyway i have edited the question. can you read it again?thanks again.

Comment: Isn't it the same ? Only the format change. If you want to display 4 digits in your result just reformat. 0001 = 1, so...

Comment: my next questions is how to manually interrupt the code after some amount of time(i am not sure about the time, the time is flexible, sometimes it can be 5minutes 30 seconds, sometimes it can be 4minutes 59 seconds),therefore i prefer to manually interrupt the code.

Comment: haha, clement, i am a beginner, therefore thank you for your guidance

Comment: @pythonbeginner as it is said in previous commentary this timing related question is  separated from your first question. Therefore, for clarity purpose and archives you should and you must ask this in a new question.

Comment: clement. thank you for your answer. i did not know the rule. i will ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this.

```
import time
import random 
from collections import Counter
from tqdm import tqdm

def most_common(a,b,top=5):
    start = time.time()
    rands = []

    time_in_min = 15
    print('Set maximum time is :',time_in_min,' minutes. You can stop before that')
    pbar = tqdm(total=1000)




    pbar = tqdm(total=1000)
    while time.time()-start<time_in_min*60:
        pbar.update(1000)
        rands.append(random.randint(a,b))
    pbar.close()
    rands = Counter(rands)
    return rands.most_common(top)

most_common(0,100,5)
#[(14, 53415), (59, 53269), (15, 53229), (42, 53223), (19, 53222)]
```

Comment: thank you for being helpful. appreciate it. anyway i have edited the question. can you read it again?thanks again.

Comment: Do you want to see the time while the program started?

Comment: thank you for your answer. however, how to stop the program and get the result before 15 minutes ?Set maximum time is : 15  minutes. You can stop before that

Comment: haha,  Anurag Maurya, i am a beginner, therefore thank you for your guidance